# @EJB injection with Arquillian on WebLogic 10.3.5 doesn't work

Tags: ejb-3.0, weblogic-10.x, jboss-arquillian

I am using Arquillian to run a basic unit test on WebLogic 10.3.5. Unfortunately, @EJB injection does not work for me, and get a NullPointerException when the EJB is invoked.

The examples I found don't require an ejb-jar.xml to be added, but I added one. In any case, a NullPointerException is thrown.

Any ideas?

The unit test:

```
import static org.testng.Assert.assertEquals;
import java.io.File;
import javax.ejb.EJB;
import org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.api.Deployment;
import org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.ShrinkWrap;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.exporter.ZipExporter;
import org.jboss.shrinkwrap.api.spec.JavaArchive;
import org.testng.annotations.Test;
import eu.ema.eudract.results.DummyService;
import eu.ema.eudract.results.DummyServiceBean;

public class ResultStatefulServiceBeanIntegrationTest extends Arquillian {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        JavaArchive archive = ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class, "test.jar")
                .addClasses(DummyService.class, DummyServiceBean.class)
                .addAsManifestResource("META-INF/ejb-jar.xml", "ejb-jar.xml");

        System.out.println(archive.toString(true));
        archive.as(ZipExporter.class).exportTo(new File("C:\\Users\\fragkakm\\Desktop\\test.jar"), true);
        return archive;
    }

    @EJB
    private DummyService dummyService;

    @Test
    public void loadResultTest() {
        assertEquals(dummyService.doNothing(), "Did nothing!");
    }
}
```

The output:

```
test.jar:
/META-INF/
/META-INF/ejb-jar.xml
/eu/
/eu/ema/
/eu/ema/eudract/
/eu/ema/eudract/results/
/eu/ema/eudract/results/DummyServiceBean.class
/eu/ema/eudract/results/DummyService.class
25 Ιουν 2012 4:31:35 μμ org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient deploy
INFO: Starting weblogic.Deployer to deploy the test artifact.
25 Ιουν 2012 4:31:42 μμ org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient forkWebLogicDeployer
INFO: weblogic.Deployer appears to have terminated successfully.
25 Ιουν 2012 4:31:45 μμ org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient undeploy
INFO: Starting weblogic.Deployer to undeploy the test artifact.
25 Ιουν 2012 4:31:51 μμ org.jboss.arquillian.container.wls.WebLogicDeployerClient forkWebLogicDeployer
INFO: weblogic.Deployer appears to have terminated successfully.
FAILED: loadResultTest
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at eu.ema.eudract.results.result.ResultStatefulServiceBeanIntegrationTest.loadResultTest(ResultStatefulServiceBeanIntegrationTest.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:80)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper$1.runTestMethod(MethodInvocationHelper.java:182)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian$2.invoke(Arquillian.java:167)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.LocalTestExecuter.execute(LocalTestExecuter.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:115)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventImpl.fire(EventImpl.java:67)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.container.test.impl.execution.ContainerTestExecuter.execute(ContainerTestExecuter.java:38)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.invokeObservers(EventContextImpl.java:99)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:81)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createTestContext(TestContextHandler.java:89)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createClassContext(TestContextHandler.java:75)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.TestContextHandler.createSuiteContext(TestContextHandler.java:60)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ObserverImpl.invoke(ObserverImpl.java:90)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.EventContextImpl.proceed(EventContextImpl.java:88)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.core.impl.ManagerImpl.fire(ManagerImpl.java:135)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.test.impl.EventTestRunnerAdaptor.test(EventTestRunnerAdaptor.java:111)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.Arquillian.run(Arquillian.java:158)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke0(Native Method)
    at sun.reflect.NativeMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(NativeMethodAccessorImpl.java:39)
    at sun.reflect.DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.invoke(DelegatingMethodAccessorImpl.java:25)
    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:597)
    at org.testng.internal.MethodInvocationHelper.invokeHookable(MethodInvocationHelper.java:194)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeMethod(Invoker.java:695)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethod(Invoker.java:894)
    at org.testng.internal.Invoker.invokeTestMethods(Invoker.java:1219)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.invokeTestMethods(TestMethodWorker.java:127)
    at org.testng.internal.TestMethodWorker.run(TestMethodWorker.java:111)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.privateRun(TestRunner.java:767)
    at org.testng.TestRunner.run(TestRunner.java:617)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runTest(SuiteRunner.java:334)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.runSequentially(SuiteRunner.java:329)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.privateRun(SuiteRunner.java:291)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunner.run(SuiteRunner.java:240)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.runSuite(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:53)
    at org.testng.SuiteRunnerWorker.run(SuiteRunnerWorker.java:87)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesSequentially(TestNG.java:1197)
    at org.testng.TestNG.runSuitesLocally(TestNG.java:1122)
    at org.testng.TestNG.run(TestNG.java:1030)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.testng.container.TestNGTestRunner.execute(TestNGTestRunner.java:53)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.executeTest(ServletTestRunner.java:160)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.execute(ServletTestRunner.java:126)
    at org.jboss.arquillian.protocol.servlet.runner.ServletTestRunner.doGet(ServletTestRunner.java:90)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:707)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:820)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper$ServletServiceAction.run(StubSecurityHelper.java:227)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.StubSecurityHelper.invokeServlet(StubSecurityHelper.java:125)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:300)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletStubImpl.execute(ServletStubImpl.java:183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.wrapRun(WebAppServletContext.java:3717)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext$ServletInvocationAction.run(WebAppServletContext.java:3681)
    at weblogic.security.acl.internal.AuthenticatedSubject.doAs(AuthenticatedSubject.java:321)
    at weblogic.security.service.SecurityManager.runAs(SecurityManager.java:120)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.securedExecute(WebAppServletContext.java:2277)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.WebAppServletContext.execute(WebAppServletContext.java:2183)
    at weblogic.servlet.internal.ServletRequestImpl.run(ServletRequestImpl.java:1454)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.execute(ExecuteThread.java:209)
    at weblogic.work.ExecuteThread.run(ExecuteThread.java:178)
```

My EJB interface:

```
package eu.ema.eudract.results;

import javax.ejb.Remote;

@Remote
public interface DummyService {

    String doNothing();
}
```

The EJB implementation:

```
package eu.ema.eudract.results;

import javax.ejb.Stateless;

import eu.ema.eudract.results.DummyService;

@Stateless
public class DummyServiceBean implements DummyService {

    public String doNothing() {
        return "Did nothing!";
    }

}
```

The arquillian.xml

```
<?xml version="1.0"?>
<arquillian xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"
    xmlns="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian"
    xsi:schemaLocation="http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian http://jboss.org/schema/arquillian/arquillian_1_0.xsd">

    <container qualifier="arquillian-wls-remote-10.3" default="true">
        <configuration>
            <property name="adminUrl">t3://localhost:7001</property>
            <property name="adminUserName">weblogic</property>
            <property name="adminPassword">aaaaaaaa</property>
            <property name="wlsHome">C:\dbin\wls1035_dev\wlserver\</property>
            <property name="target">AdminServer</property>
        </configuration>
    </container>

</arquillian>
```

The dependencies I've added:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-bom</artifactId>
    <version>1.0.1.Final</version>
    <scope>import</scope>
    <type>pom</type>
</dependency>
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.jboss.arquillian.container</groupId>
    <artifactId>arquillian-wls-remote-10.3</artifactId>
    <scope>test</scope>
    <version>1.0.0.Alpha2</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

WLS 10.3.5 is a JEE5 compliant container, so you cannot have an EJB resident in a web-module (which is supported since JEE6 i.e. WLS 12c).

To allow for EJBs to be injected into your test class in WLS 10.3.x, you'll need to provide the associated `ejb-local-ref` entries in your web.xml of your ShrinkWrap `WebArchive`. If you prepare an EAR archive, then you'll need to add these entries into the `WebArchive` that would be enriched with the Arquillian Servlet Testrunner.

An example of this is available in the Arquillian GitHub repository [in the WebLogicInjectionTestCase](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-wls/blob/master/wls-remote-10.3/src/test/java/org/jboss/arquillian/container/wls/remote_10_3/WebLogicInjectionTestCase.java) class. The associated web.xml file is [in-container-web-eartest.xml](https://github.com/arquillian/arquillian-container-wls/blob/master/wls-remote-10.3/src/test/resources/in-container-web-eartest.xml).

Note that the ejb-local-ref entries are definitely required when you attempt injection of Local EJBs, since WLS does not bind them in the JNDI tree, by default. You might be able to skip this prerequisite for remote EJBs.

Comment: The links are dead.