# @EJB injection in Arquillian fails due to "Unable to inject resource - most probably incorrect InjectionServices SPI implementation"

Tags: java, jakarta-ee, dependency-injection, jboss-arquillian

I'm getting started with Arquillian following [the general getting started guide](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started/) which I can reproduce successfully, but [using it for EJB testing](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/) fails due to `Unable to inject resource - most probably incorrect InjectionServices SPI implementation` which causes the `@EJB` property to be not injected/`null` can thus the test to fail.

An extension of the greeter example demonstrates the issue:

```
@Local
public interface GreeterIface {

    void greet(PrintStream to, String name);

    String createGreeting(String name);
}
```

EJB:

```
@Stateless
public class Greeter implements GreeterIface{
    @Override
    public void greet(PrintStream to, String name) {
        to.println(createGreeting(name));
    }

    @Override
    public String createGreeting(String name) {
        return "Hello, " + name + "!";
    }
}
```

and the test:

```
@RunWith(Arquillian.class)
public class GreeterTest {

    @Deployment
    public static JavaArchive createDeployment() {
        return ShrinkWrap.create(JavaArchive.class)
            .addClasses(Greeter.class, GreeterIface.class)
            .addAsManifestResource(EmptyAsset.INSTANCE, "beans.xml");
    }

    @EJB
    private Greeter greeter;

    @Test
    public void should_create_greeting() {
        Assert.assertEquals("Hello, Earthling!",
            greeter.createGreeting("Earthling"));
        greeter.greet(System.out, "Earthling");
    }
}
```

fails due to

```
Jun 20, 2017 3:03:19 PM org.jboss.weld.injection.AbstractResourceInjection getResourceReference
WARN: WELD-000834: Unable to inject resource - most probably incorrect InjectionServices SPI implementation: private richtercloud.arquillian.demo.Greeter richtercloud.arquillian.demo.GreeterTest.greeter
    at richtercloud.arquillian.demo.GreeterTest.greeter(GreeterTest.java:0)
Tests run: 1, Failures: 0, Errors: 1, Skipped: 0, Time elapsed: 1.012 sec <<< FAILURE! - in richtercloud.arquillian.demo.GreeterTest
should_create_greeting(richtercloud.arquillian.demo.GreeterTest)  Time elapsed: 0.035 sec  <<< ERROR!
java.lang.NullPointerException: null
    at richtercloud.arquillian.demo.GreeterTest.should_create_greeting(GreeterTest.java:33)
```

The best, yet unusable hints are delivered by

- [@EJB injection with Arquillian on WebLogic 10.3.5 doesn't work](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11190475/ejb-injection-with-arquillian-on-weblogic-10-3-5-doesnt-work) (contains dead links and it menitons `WebArchive` whereas the official guide uses a `JarArchive` for both SE and EE, so I assume `JarArchive` is correct)
- [Dependency injection does not work in Arquillian Test](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/21456080/dependency-injection-does-not-work-in-arquillian-test) covers injection failure, but it's causes by missing classes in the archive which is not the case for me
- [Injecting @Stateless EJB in Arquillian tests](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/35743240/injecting-stateless-ejb-in-arquillian-tests) is about the failure `Unsatisfied dependencies for type [MyEjbRemote] with qualifiers [@Default] at injection point [[field] @Inject private com.org.app.ejb.InjectionTest.ejb]` which I also got at one point, but don't remember when, in this large stream of unhelpful non-explaining failure messages

MCVEs are https://github.com/krichter722/arquillian-demo (extended Java SE project which is supposed to work based on guide) and https://github.com/krichter722/arquillian-demo-2 (my own Java EE project)

I'm using Arquillian 1.1.13.Final.

Comment: As I can see, the tests use weld-se, not an ejb-container, so "@EJB @Resource, @Transact" ... won't work. If the starting of a wildfly for the tests is to much effort, there are extensions which are made to do a simulation of EJB in a test environment perhaps cdi-unit and ejb-cdi-unit can help. See github, for further documentation.

Answer (score 0):

How does your pom.xml looks like? You need to add some additional information so that arquillian can startup a container and run the tests.

In the "getting started" guide they are running a CDI only application and using weld as implementation to manage the injection of needed beans. But in your case you want to test the injection of a stateless bean. In that case you need to add a container like jboss/wildfly or glassfish to run the tests.

This arquillian guide shows how to use `@EJB` in an arquillian test:
[Getting Started: Rinse and Repeat](http://arquillian.org/guides/getting_started_rinse_and_repeat/#add_the_remote_containers)

In the guide JBoss AS 7 is used. If you want to use wildfly 10 instead, you can use the following dependency:

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.wildfly.arquillian</groupId>
    <artifactId>wildfly-arquillian-container-remote</artifactId>
    <version>2.1.0.Alpha3</version>
</dependency>
```

Answer (score 0):

A solution would be to use the Arquillian adapter for the embedded TomEE container (based on OpenEJB). Add to your test dependencies:

```xml
         <dependency>
            <groupId>org.apache.tomee</groupId>
            <artifactId>arquillian-openejb-embedded</artifactId>
            <version>7.0.5</version> <!-- or whatever version you need -->
            <scope>test</scope>
         </dependency>
```